# How to change Button text size in iOS 8 swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I have got a button with a layout `outletLeaderboard`.
I want to change his text size by the code, so this is what I wrote:

```
outletLeaderboard.font =  UIFont(name: outletLeaderboard.font.fontName, size: 37)
```

and then I get an error:

> 'font' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are
>   unavailable in Swift

What is the correct line I need to write?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `titleLabel` instead of `.font`

```
outletLeaderboard.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 20)
```

Comment: My font name is costumed: Helvetica Neue Thin. How do I write it in the code line?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
outletLeaderboard.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: outletLeaderboard.font.fontName, size: 37)
```

Comment: I still get that error: 'font' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

Answer (score 2):

Simply access the title label of the button. For example:

```
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-MT", size: 15)
```

Comment: What if my font name is costumed: Helvetica Neue Thin. How do I write it in the code line?

Comment: Your Button already have this costumed font ? Then try : `  button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(descriptor:(button.titleLabel?.font.fontDescriptor())!, size: 15) `

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 3:

```
if let titleLabel = outletLeaderboard.titleLabel {
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: titleLabel.font.fontName, size: 16)
}
```

or even better an extension:

```
extension UIButton {
    func set(fontSize: CGFloat) {
        if let titleLabel = titleLabel {
             titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: titleLabel.font.fontName, size: fontSize)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you've defined outletLeaderboard, make sure its  of  UIButton type.

```
var outletLeaderboard : UIButton = UIButton()
outletLeaderboard.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Consolas", size: 30)
```