# How to increase Font Size in button Pragmatically (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, button, text, swift3

I would like the user to have the ability to make the text larger.

I have figured out how to increase a button overall size but the text remains the same.

```swift
button.frame =  CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50)
```

How to increase Font Size in button Pragmatically in swift3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Button text size in iOS 8 swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922387/how-to-change-button-text-size-in-ios-8-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use titleLabel, like this:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
```

You can use UIFont in a lot of ways, check it's constructor!